# Angularjs: How to pre-select input text field on page load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple text input field in my angular app which is prefilled with a default value. I want to preselect the text on page load.

Input field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="city" class="form-control" select-on-load />
```

Directive:

```
weatherApp.directive('selectOnLoad', function () {
// Linker function
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('load', function () {
        this.select();
    });
};
```

});

But nothing happens.

Comment: Did you try replace `this.select()` by `element.select()` or `$(this).select()` ?

Comment: I tried element.select() as well. And I don't want to use jQuery to be honest but it wont work either.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you but you can just use autofocus to pre-select that field  <input type="text" ng-model="city" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus"/>

Comment: Doesn't work for me, have a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/6MV1SQbrTfXLRrQ0kjEQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708850/is-there-an-onload-event-for-input-elements) suggest that there is no `load` event for input elements. However, maybe you could attach the handle once the [view content has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715256/angularjs-event-to-call-after-content-is-loaded)?

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    // Set a flag
  });
```

It isn't as neat as a directive, but it's the simplest alternative to my knowledge. The event sets a flag, the element uses an `ng-focus` depending on that flag, and your original directive can be updated to listen for focus, not load.

---

EDIT: I've done some searching, and can't find any ideas of a better alternative. It does feel a lot like a hack, so I welcome anyone with a better suggestion.

Comment: I don't even know how to access the DOM elements via the controller but that's exactly what AngularJS tries to avoid. I thought any interaction with the DOM should be done via directives.

Comment: It feels a bit dirty, but consider using `ng-focus`. Have a controller variable, `viewIsLoaded` that is updated by the above handler. Then, on your view, use `ng-focus="viewIsLoaded"` to focus the box. There might be a way to avoid this - have `ng-focus` directly listen to `$viewContentLoaded` - but I don't know of it yet. I'll do some reading.

Comment: Modified my comment - what I meant was `ng-focus`. Then, your original handler listens for focus, not load, which is an available handler for input.

Comment: Sorry Tom, but I'm not entirely sure what your solution is. With ng-focus you can trigger a function in the controller when the input field gets focus, but I want to focus and select the input text simply when the page loads.

Comment: Your issue was that you can't set a load event for input. However, by setting a focus event, you can achieve the same if the input gets focus when the page is loaded. It was a pretty roundabout solution, but I think it solves the problem :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
function selectOnLoadDirective() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      elem.focus().select();
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: With function selectOnLoadDirective() { } you mean the directive I created right? If not where would you put that function?

Comment: Sure. Just copy `elem.focus().sleect();` into your link function. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

Super late but you can easily accomplish this using JS. Inside your controller...

[Example...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vfJg.png)

Then inside your html id you have an input tag with a matching id

[Easy peasy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ9zL.png)

Hope that helped!

Comment: Please [do not post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).