# Web Programming

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have created a form in html.
I have added `event listener` on file browsing field and also there is some condition to be checked before submitting the form.
So i have used

```
onsubmit="return myfunction()"
```

If myfunction is returning false, an alert window pops.
On clicking on the 'ok' of alert window the form is getting submitted.

Also the onsubmit action is not working everytime. It works just once.
So next time if I entry invalid details in form and click Submit the form is submitted.
Is there anything that I am missing ?

Comment: please include your code

Comment: You should post your relevant code; otherwise we don't have any idea what is going wrong. Also please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Comment: Edit your title to be **more specific** please.

Comment: @AbdulRafay<form name="First" action="action.jsp"  method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkfiles();">
            Email Address* :<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="20" required/><br/>
            Project Name*:<input type="text" name="pname" value="" size="20" required/><br/>
            Upload fasta file: <input type="file" id="fileInput"><br/>
            <label id="l1"></label><br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></input>
       </form>

Comment: "Is there anything that I am missing" - nope I think you've covered everything. Good luck

Comment: @AbdulRafay <script>window.onload = function() {
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var l1 = document.getElementById('l1');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {var file = fileInput.files[0];var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {var cnt=0,i=0;
 var contents = reader.result;var lines=contents.split('\n');
 while(i<4){if(lines[i].includes('>'))
 cnt=cnt+1; i=i+1;if(lines[i].match('.*^[AGCT]+$.*'))
cnt=cnt+1;i=i+1;}if(cnt!=4)l1.innerText="Not a fasta format"; 
                    }reader.readAsText(file); 
   }); } </script>

Comment: @AbdulRafayfunction checkfiles()
            {
                var fup=document.getElementById('l1');
                var t = fup.innerText;
                if(t=='Not a fasta format')
                {
                    //alert("Upload fasta format file");
                    fup.innerText="Please upload a fasta format file";
                 //out.println("upload .fa file");
                 fup.focus();
                 return false;
                }
               else
               {
                return true;            
               }
           }

Comment: You can edit your question, please do that instead of posting them as comments. Also post them as a snippet if possible. (To make a snippet click the last button in the second column and make sure it works by hitting run)

Answer (score 0):

On checking the structure of the code ! it seems you are checking the file format only during `window.onload()` which would be set to `Not a fasta format` because its `null` as no object is loaded at start, so try to include it in the function call `checkfiles()` and it should work! I guess you are trying to check the format when the user loads the file then please check the below thread [check onload for input elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708850/is-there-an-onload-event-for-input-elements)