# Automatically inserting window.location.hash into html input value?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's what I'm essentially trying to do:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="window.location.hash">
```

What's the proper way to insert the `window.location.hash` into the `input`'s `value`?

Note: I've found several ways to do this when people are required to click a button, but nothing that explains how to do it automatically when the page loads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an onload event for input elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708850/is-there-an-onload-event-for-input-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to assign this after the page loads, or at least the element

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="hash" value="">
<script>
  window.onload=function() {
     document.querySelector("#hash").value = window.location.hash
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the element and change its value using JavaScript. In this Snippet, I'm redirecting to a different hash, just for example purposes.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input.form-control");

// Redirect to different hash for example
window.location.hash = "abcdef";

input.value = window.location.hash;
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need JS script for that:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const input = document.getElementById('location');
  input.value = window.location.host; // change .host to .hash
})
```

```html
<input  id="location">
```